# How to achieve this layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Please see below, I think this should be simple but I cannot figure it out...

The goal is to make an image follows some text immediately, and when the text is long, the image can still be there and the text show ellipsis at the end. The text is only one line.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: android:singleLine="true"
 android:ellipsize="end"    
 android:drawableRight ="@drawable/ic_info"   - use this three line in xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something lke this should work:

```
<TextView   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABCABCABACBACBACBACBAC"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"    
        android:drawableRight ="@drawable/ic_info" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I listen to click event of the drawableRight? And maybe add ripple effect on touch?

Comment: @Student222 If you need to listen to events on the icon maybe your the approach with a drawableright is not the correct answer, a LinearLayout with horizontal oritentation with an inner TextView and imageView should look the same but works how you want

Answer (score 0):

try this  `android:ellipsize="end"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/images"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Large Text fgkjdsfgkjdfslgk jdsfg jdfgjdfjgijdfogjdfgdfsgdfsg dfsg  dfsg sdf g"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/images"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Student222 : did u get the answer?

Comment: Thank you! Can I listen to click event of the drawableRight? And maybe add ripple effect on touch?

Comment: u cannot add click only to drawableRight . if you need that you need to add the image separately. u cab get the click on the text

Answer (score 0):

In above comments you have asked for listener to click event on drawableRight, here is the implementation to that

```
yourTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (yourTextView.getRight() - yourTextView.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {

                        return true;
                    }

                }
                return false;
                }

        });
```